# introjs: when using intro background images appear above popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, intro.js

im using introjs, but I have a problem in somes pages of the website. I have a popup that appears in front of the page, however when I call the intro and point to elements in the popup, the images in the background appear above the popup (see image), without the intro the popup appears fine. And in other pages I do the same but all works good

the css of my popup is like this:

```
#popup_modal {
    /* position: fixed; */
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    width: 98%;
    left: 1%;
    z-index: 99999999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#popup {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #007793;
    width: 470px !important;
    min-height: 162px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #666;
}
```

[image]

EDIT:

[image]

```
#popup_modal {
    /* position: fixed; */
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    width: 98%;
    left: 1%;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#popup {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #007793;
    width: 470px !important;
    min-height: 162px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #666;
}
```

Introjs css:

```
.introjs-helperLayer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999998;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    border: 1px solid #777;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `position: relative` to the CSS for `#popup` to force layering to be calculated:

```css
#popup {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #007793;
    width: 470px !important;
    min-height: 162px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #666;
    z-index: 999999999;
    position: relative; // Default value is "static" but "relative" will cause layering to occur
}
```

Z-index values are usually ignored in statically-positioned elements, causing weird layering when you have other elements that use different types of positioning.

Comment: it happens the same :/

Comment: I notice that you edited the question to remove the z-index value from `#popup`. You will want to have that in there, too, like in my example. If it still isn't working, then it'll be difficult to suggest anything else without examining the CSS for the elements that are showing through.

Comment: It's also possible that intro.js is setting a z-index on the popup, causing it to be overlapped by the other elements. If that's the case, you can set it with !important and see if that helps (at least to determine why it's happening). Again, it's hard to say without examining the CSS. If you can provide a JSFiddle example or point us to a page where this is located, it would help a ton.

Comment: I tried to change z-index on #popup but nothing happens, but if I change z-index on #popup_modal with important it appears like this (check edit image on question). but like that I cant select the box :|

Comment: I can't put all of this in a jsfiddle, because it need the popup + introjs + background stuff :/

Comment: When you say you can't select the box, which box do you mean?

Comment: Ohhhhhh. I see what you're saying. Took me a minute to see it. Without seeing the CSS of the various elements, it's really hard to offer a suggestion. I don't want you to have to put in a bunch of different z-indexes just to get things to layer the way you want. What I can tell from the image is that the item you're trying to highlight is layering beneath the "box." You could use alpha masking to punch holes in the overlay and the box, but that's getting pretty hacky. The more code you can provide as an example, the easier it will be to help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this
[image]

After adding inline style in li element of sidebar (style="background-color:#347D87!important;") and adding property 'position:absolute' of class 'introjs-fixedTooltip' in original introjs.css file IT worked!!!

[image]

I have spent more than 10 hours with this issue I couldnt find better solution.

Updated:
https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/532

Answer (score 0):

just use this css :

```
.introjs-fixParent {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

`introjs-fixPrent` is placed on top parent of that element so and please use `setTimeOut` function to move on steps.